# Is Hibernate Validator @NotNull always triggered first?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

In other words if I have two constraints like `@Email` and `@NotNull` the `@Email` validator won't throw a NPE?

It seems obvious but I'm asking because I saw that some custom validators check whether the value to be validated is null and return true if it is.  This seems like a bad idea because if the developer forgot to add `@NotNull` to the `email` field, then the email field will still pass validation.

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `true` for `null` is considered best practice in Bean
Validation and all built-in constraints adhere to it (where possible).
The Bean Validation spec says in section [3.4. Constraint validation implementation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-validationimplementation):

> While not mandatory, it is considered a good practice to split the
>   core constraint validation from the not null constraint validation
>   (for example, an @Email constraint will return true on a null object,
>   i.e. will not take care of the @NotNull validation).
>
> null can have multiple meanings but is commonly used to express that a
>   value does not make sense, is not available or is simply unknown.
>   Those constraints on the value are orthogonal in most cases to other
>   constraints. For example a String, if present, must be an email but
>   can be null. Separating both concerns is a good practice.